# SPFX Getting Sharepoint Online Modern Page ListItem Icon Programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I'm trying to get Modern Page ListItem icon path for some implementation.

I understand that for SharePoint OnPrem / Online Classic, 
it will be located under `/_layouts/15/images/<<icon_filename>>`

On Modern pages, on inspect element, it shows that the icon is coming from another source. I assume its SPO OOTB CDN.

Let's say txt icon is on

```
https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/odsp-next-prod_ship-2017-09-08-sts_20170928.001/odsp-media/images/filetypes/16/txt.png
```

and list item folder icon is on

```
https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/odsp-next-prod_ship-2017-09-08-sts_20170928.001/odsp-media/images/filetypes/16/folder.svg
```

I worry that the url may change in the future, **is there any way to get these URLs programmatically?**

```
var hostURL = //some code refering to https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/odsp-next-prod_ship-2017-09-08-sts_20170928.001/odsp-media/images/filetypes/16
var fileURL = hostURL + "folder.svg";
```